# Photoshop Save Dialog CAN'T SHRINK?

Tags: windows-10, photoshop-cs6, illustrator-cs6

So, I was using Photoshop, and went to save a document, when I stretched the save dialog bigger, and randomly could **no longer shrink it**. The same thing happened in Illustrator as well.

[image: Unshrinkable window]

**Details:**
I'm using Windows 10 with multiple desktops. I tried restarting the programs, and my computer - neither did anything. Is there some settings file I can clear?

Comment: Same problem with Google Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I haven't necessarily found a way to make it *shrinkable*, but I did at least find a way to restore it to normal, as long as I don't stretch it big again.

It's another Windows 10 error. [This site](http://www.tenforums.com/software-apps/15714-save-dialog-resize-problem.html) gave me some direction:

The window dialog sizes can be found in the registry in the following key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ComDlg32\CIDSizeMRU
```

Deleting all the entries except `(Default)`, `0`, and `MRUListEx` will reset the window dimensions to default, including those of Adobe's save dialogs.